# React-Select: Page turns white after selecting an option

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-select

I am pretty new to React and am trying to use React-Select for a simple dropdown menu.
When you selected an option it should display the value under it, for that I'm using the onChange function and the useState Hook, but everytime I select something, the whole page just turns white.

**App.js**

```
import "./App.css";
import Select from "react-select";
import { useState } from "react";

function App() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(0);

  const options = [
    { value: "1", label: "a" },
    { value: "2", label: "b" },
    { value: "3", label: "c" },
  ];

  return (
    <div>
      <Select placeholder="Choose one"
      defaultValue={selected}
      onChange={setSelected}
      options={options}
      />
      <h1>{selected}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've done a simple edit on your code:

- When `onChange` fires you set the selected value with `onChange={(e)=>setSelected(e.value)}`

Here's a functional [codesandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/onchange-react-select-stackoverflow-r9z57)

Comment: Hey, that works perfect and is much sleeker than my way. Thank you very much.

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect your console in the browser, you'll see the issue is coming from the h1 component. This is probably what you're trying to achieve:

```
     <h1>{selected.value}</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that didn't work, when I hover over 'value', it says: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'. 
But I found another way that works, I'm gonna post ist as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to solve this, however I don't know if this is the best solution.

**I created a function handleChange**

```
const handleChange = e => {
    setSelected(e.value);
  }
```

**and added a value prop, and called the function with onChange**

```
<Select placeholder="Choose one"
      defaultValue={selected}
      value={options.find(obj => obj.value === selected)}
      onChange={handleChange}
      options={options}
      />
```

I don't know why

```
<h1>{selected.value}<h1>
```

doesn't work, since it's practically the same what I'm doing in handleChange, right?